# Using jquery datatables I can't make a cell colspan=3 without breaking FixedHead

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables

I have a fixedhead datatable with the first 4 rows fixed to the top when scrolling down, the problem is that when I try to make the second row colspan=3 the one that says “make me colspan=3” the datatable loses its ability to be fixed to the top. I don’t know why that could affect the datatable. Thank you for your help.
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/139/

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan=3></th>
        <th colspan=3>234</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Make me </th>
        <th>colspan</th>
        <th>=3</th>
        <th>
            <p class="rotatehead">Hazmat</p>
        </th>
        <th>
            <p class="rotatehead">Out of Area</p>
        </th>
        <th>
            <p class="rotatehead">Lite</p>
        </th>
    </tr>
```

UPDATE: I just saw my console after adding the colspan=3 and I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefinedjquery.dataTables.js:4138 _fnCalculateColumnWidthsjquery.dataTables.js:3265 _fnInitialisejquery.dataTables.js:6521 (anonymous function)jquery-1.8.3.js:611 jQuery.extend.eachjquery-1.8.3.js:241 jQuery.fn.jQuery.eachjquery.dataTables.js:6047 DataTablejquery.dataTables.js:14691 $.fn.DataTablepriceadjustment.html:30 (anonymous function)jquery-1.8.3.js:974 jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery-1.8.3.js:1084 jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery-1.8.3.js:406 jQuery.extend.readyjquery-1.8.3.js:83 DOMContentLoaded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [DataTables complex header](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html) documentation:

> Note that each column must have at least one unique cell (i.e. a cell without colspan) so DataTables can use that cell to detect the column and use it to apply ordering.

In your example, the header `column` that you are trying to apply the `colspan` to does not contain a "unique cell".

You can get around this, however, by adding a single head row without `colspan` and then setting it's css to `display:none;`:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/156/)

**Header Example:**

```
 <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=3></th>
            <th colspan=3>234</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- ADDED: Placeholder row for sorting -->
        <tr class="place">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- END Placeholder row for sorting -->
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Make me colspan = 3</th>
            <th>
                <p class="rotatehead">Hazmat</p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p class="rotatehead">Out of Area</p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p class="rotatehead">Lite</p>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=3>RACK</th>
            <th>
                <div contenteditable>234</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div contenteditable>234</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div contenteditable>234</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=3>TOTAL</th>
            <th>
                <div contenteditable>234</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div contenteditable>234</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div contenteditable>345</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

**Added CSS:**

```
.place{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That was brilliant! The answer and the workaround. Thanks man I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks! Happy to have helped.